# Tomcat fails to load webapp when it is running as a windows service

Tags: java, tomcat, windows-services, tomcat7, tomcat6

I am using tomcat 7 and I have a webapp which has 1 configuration file & 1 hazelcast.xml file in tomcat bin directory. When I start tomcat as a process from startup.bat catalina.timestamp.log shows `INFO: Configuring Hazelcast from 'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0_ApacheTomcat7\bin\hazelcast.xml'.` and everything works fine, but when I start the same webapp by starting tomcat as a windows service it goes to tomcat home dir and looks for the file here `INFO: Configuring Hazelcast from 'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0_ApacheTomcat7\hazelcast.xml'.`

Is there any jvm or tomcat option that I need to place?

below is my Java Options which is set in Tomcat properties

```
-Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0_ApacheTomcat7
-Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0_ApacheTomcat7
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0_ApacheTomcat7\endorsed
-Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0_ApacheTomcat7\temp
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0_ApacheTomcat7\conf\logging.properties
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem.

When I start Tomcat as a Windows service it sets the current working dir to `%CATALINA_HOME%`. So I added `--StartPath=%CATALINA_HOME%\bin` in `service.bat` (details [here](http://www.dustinthecloud.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=140:setup-the-working-directory-on-tomcat-running-as-a-windows-service&catid=35:apache-tomcat&Itemid=66)) and installed a fresh service like so: `service.bat install MyService`.

[image: screenshot showing where entry for StartPath has to be made]

Incase one does not have `service.bat` but `tomcat6`: below is the command to create a fresh windows service.

```
tomcat6 //IS//MyService --DisplayName="My Service Name" \ --Install="C:\tomcat6\bin\tomcat6.exe" --Jvm=auto \ --StartMode=jvm --StopMode=jvm \ --StartClass=org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap --StartParams=start \ --StopClass=org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap --StopParams=stop \ --StartPath=C:\tomcat6\bin
```

You can even set this in the Tomcat GUI: `Startup` tab | `Start parameters`.
(The Tomcat GUI is also known as the "Commons Daemon Service Manager". Default name is `tomcat7w.exe`, or "YOURSERVICENAMEHEREw.exe".)